# Changed my server's IP address do I need to regenerate my SSH key?

Tags: linux, networking, ssh

I had to move a server to a different subnet and re-IP it. Users are trying to run the following command:

```
sftp <username>@<my server>
```

and its timing out. I've confirmed that my health checks are passing in my F5 for ports 21 and 22.

If I telnet on port 22 from any machine it works. But sftp does not. Could this be an issue with the SSH key since the IP changed? How would I go about fixing it?

Comment: When you say `@<my server>` are users connecting via DNS name or IP address?  If DNS name, there could be a DNS cache / TTL issue if the change was made only recently.  Did you try to connect via the new IP address in your tests?  Also, it's odd that you are testing telnet to port 22 - that shouldn't work, unless you are merely testing if the port is open.  Any chance there is some (port) redirection occurring in some firewall between the users and the server?

Answer (score 1):

The server's fingerprint will change regardless.

If the users are connecting to user@hostname then their client's known_hosts file or equivalent may well reject the connection as it seems to be a possible man-in-the-middle attack. They should be getting an error or some sort of message about this.

Affected users would need to delete their client's record of hostname's fingerprint.

Comment: The "server fingerprint" (host key) will *NOT* change if all that changed was the IP address of the server.   However, if the users are connecting via IP address, and therefore the IP is being stored in the `known_hosts`, and there was a previous `ssh` server at the same address, this might be a correct analysis.